# Bokeh Dynamically Update xrange based on a ColumnDataSource

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there a way to update the xaxis of a bar chart using a columndatasource object? I have a chart that updates the bars based off of what is selected, but I want the tick marks in the xaxis to only represent the values that are being displayed. So, I figured the best option would be to dynamically update the xrange as each new value is selected, similar to how the overall plot is changed based on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `FactorRange` objects are only configurable by setting the `factors` property of the range. It is not possible to link the `factors` property to a CDS directly. (Factor ranges support multi-level hierarchical levels, and that does not map naturally to CDS columns.) However, you can change the value of `factors` to whatever you need, in a `CustomJS` callback, or Python callback (if are making a Bokeh server application).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I created a function that alters the bars based on selection, so, should I add the Python callback to that already existing method?

Comment: It sounds like the callback that alters the bars is already the appropriate place to also update the range factors at the same time.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but for example, to update the bars, I have the following:

`market = select.value
    newSource = newDF(market)
source.data = newSource.data
`

This automatically updates the previous CDS data to the new CDS data. Is there something similar I can do for the x_range?

Comment: e.g. `plot.x_range.factors = new_list_of_factors`

Comment: Ok. Thank you! I will try that out.